# Are references usually optimized away?

Tags: c++, c++14, compiler-optimization, c++17

Consider this piece of code example:

```
// Static variables
void Object::f_v1()
{
    static const int& foo = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo;
    static const int& bar = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar;
    static const int& baz = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz;
    return foo * foo + baz * bar + baz / bar + baz;
}

// References
void Object::f_v2()
{
    const int& foo = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo;
    const int& bar = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar;
    const int& baz = dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz;
    return foo * foo + baz * bar + baz / bar + baz;
}

// Everything written out
void Object::f_v3()
{
    return dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo * dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz * dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz / dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz;
}
```

Which one of these would be the best performancewise, with compiler-optimizations turned on?

- The static version constructs the reference only once, but always
  checks for mutex-locks after that.
- The normal reference version
  should calculate the address only once, but will the shortcuts be
  completely optimized away in either this version or in the last
  version?

  - If not, what is faster, a check for a mutex-lock each time
    or generating references?

I'm using **gcc 7.1 with -O3.**

Comment: Why don't you look at the generated code for each of the functions?

Comment: Shame on me, but I cant read assembly.

Comment: Is whatever minuscule speed gain you may or may not get from a particular form worth the possible decreased readability?

Comment: Problem with optimising a code fragment (or even commenting on possible optimisations) is that (1) measurement in context is everything and (2) with the mayor compilers now doing whole-program-optimisation(s) small changes elsewhere (say the call site) can have large results.

Comment: Use something like https://gcc.godbolt.org/ . You don't need assembly skills to tell if resulting assembly for your functions is same or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are references usually optimized away?

If they can be, yes they are usually optimized away.

`f_v1` has different behaviour than the others unless `dataObjectConstRef` itself refers to a static object. It also has some performance penalty due to synchronization that is required in case the function is called from multiple threads. As a rule of thumb: thread synchronization tends to be slower than assignment of a pointer / reference. But measure if it is important.

Assuming those fields actually have type `int` (and therefore no conversions are involved) `f_v2` and `f_v3` have same behaviour. It should be easy for the compiler to prove this, and I would expect an optimizing compiler to produce exactly the same code for both.

Comment: Good answer; I'd note that some care is taken in the C++ standard to ensure references don't have a separate "identity" to what they refer to; their size is unspecified, you cannot get a pointer to them, structures they are in are treated differently than those without, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling a minimal example:

```
struct DataObject
{
  struct DataField
  {
    double foo, bar, baz;
  } dataField;
};

struct Object
{

// Everything written out
double f_v3()
{
    return dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo * dataObjectConstRef.dataField.foo + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz * dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz / dataObjectConstRef.dataField.bar + 
         dataObjectConstRef.dataField.baz;
}
  DataObject const& dataObjectConstRef;
};

extern const DataObject const& getData();

int main()
{
  Object o { getData() };
  return o.f_v3();
}
```

With clang 3.9, -O3:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        call    getData()
        vmovsd  xmm0, qword ptr [rax]   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
        vmovsd  xmm1, qword ptr [rax + 8] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vmovsd  xmm2, qword ptr [rax + 16] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero
        vmulsd  xmm3, xmm2, xmm1
        vaddsd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm3
        vdivsd  xmm1, xmm2, xmm1
        vaddsd  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
        vaddsd  xmm0, xmm2, xmm0
        vcvttsd2si      eax, xmm0
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

Results in only 3 loads (`vmovsd`).

So yes, the dereferencing of reference has been optimised away in this case.

The c++ standard allows the compiler to do this because the optimised code results in the same outcome *as if* the original source code had been executed verbatim.